# XML Serialization suppressing separate nodes for each class

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am trying to convert a multiple record flat file to xml.  I have a separate class for each record type.  Some of the classes will only have one instance and don't need to be separated by a "class node".  Some have multiple occurances and do need to be separated.  I can't find any help on ignoring/removing the class name when using xml serializer.

```
public class Class1
{
    public string StringA;
    public string StringB;
    public string StringC;

}
public class Class2
{
    public string StringD;
    public string StringE;
    public string StringF;
}
 public class Class3
{
    public string Name;
    public Class1 User1 = new Class1 { StringA = "A String", StringB = "B String", StringC = "C String" };
    public Class2 User2 = new Class2 { StringD = "D String", StringE = "E String", StringF = "F String" };

}
```

Here is the serialization:

```
XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Class3));
var test = new Class3();
test.Name = "Name";
x.Serialize(Console.Out, test);
```

I get the following:

```
<Class3>
<Name>Name</Name> 
<User1>
  <StringA>A String</StringA> 
  <StringB>B String</StringB> 
  <StringC>C String</StringC> 
</User1>
<User2>
  <StringD>D String</StringD> 
  <StringE>E String</StringE> 
  <StringF>F String</StringF> 
</User2>
```

I want the  and  nodes to disapear and become:

```
<Class3>
  <Name>Name</Name>
  <StringA>A String</StringA>
  <StringB>B String</StringB>
  <StringC>C String</StringC>
  <StringD>D String</StringD>
  <StringE>E String</StringE>
  <StringF>F String</StringF>
</Class3>
```

Comment: For getting that kind of output you would have to either create an object with name and all the string properties flattened or work out your custom serialization to flatten the objects. Default serialization will always nest the objects so that it know how to deserialize it later. Here is some info on how to implement your custom serialization http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -1):

Easiest and most flexible way is going to be to implement IXmlSerializable (at least on Class3).

You may want to check this out: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43237/How-to-Implement-IXmlSerializable-Correctly

```
public class Class3 : IXmlSerializable
{
    public string Name;
    public Class1 User1 = new Class1 
    {
        StringA = "A String",
        StringB = "B String",
        StringC = "C String"
    };

    public Class2 User2 = new Class2
    {
        StringD = "D String",
        StringE = "E String",
        StringF = "F String"
    };

    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {

    }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteElementString("Name", Name);
        writer.WriteElementString("StringA", User1.StringA);
        writer.WriteElementString("StringB", User1.StringB);
        writer.WriteElementString("StringC", User1.StringC);

        writer.WriteElementString("StringD", User2.StringD);
        writer.WriteElementString("StringE", User2.StringE);
        writer.WriteElementString("StringF", User2.StringF);

    }
```

Comment: -1: please fix your links to point to the latest documentation. Preferably, link to the document without the "(v=vs.something)" in the URL.